# How to set last modified time based on the request header 'Last-Modified' on Python

Tags: python

I want to get the `last modified time` from the `url response header`, and then write the response to a local file, and set the last modified time on that local file.

**Here is the python code:**

```
r = session.get(url)

url_time = r.headers['Last-Modified']

with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
    
os.utime(file_name, (url_time, url_time))
```

**Here is the error output:**

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

How to convert the url_time to the specified "integer" for os.utime?

**The code to print the url_time:**

```
print("url_time: {}".format(url_time))
```

**Here is the output of url_time:**

```
url_time: Tue, 08 Feb 2022 14:32:27 GMT
```

Comment: It depends on the format `url_time` is in. Can you try printing it and share the result?

Comment: I have added the output of url_time, please help to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use the `datetime` module to convert the string into a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object, then use that object to get the timestamp:

```
last_updated_pattern = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
timestamp = int(datetime.strptime(url_time, last_updated_pattern).timestamp())
os.utime(file_name, (timestamp, timestamp))
```

You can see the documentation for the format of the pattern for decoding time strings [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). You may also want to review the documentation for the datetime object if it is not handling timezones or other properties of the time like you expect